# Bitlocker Encryption on RAID 0 kicks drive out of array half-way through

Tags: raid, megaraid, bitlocker

After hunting around for answers, I found some for the question: "Does Bitlocker support RAID on Windows". The answer seems to be that hardware RAID is supported.

I've got a RAID 0 drive that I wanted to test this on, so I began the Bitlocker encryption on it. It's not a large drive, 1.3TB usable, and at 58.3% encryption, it was kicked out of the MegaRAID manager and marked as foreign. This, of course, stops the ongoing encryption.

I can import the foreign configuration, use the password to unlock the drive, and Windows will try again, but a few seconds later it gets kicked out of the array again.

I was under the impression this should work. Is there some incompatibility with MegaRAID that is the problem, or should I be using a different option somewhere?

As usual, Windows Event Viewer wasn't helpful:

`An error was encountered converting volume G:.`

`Unexpected failure. Error code: 2@01010013`

`Disk 4 has been surprise removed.`

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we use Mega-Raid on different Controllers with Raid1 and 5 and bitlock those, I can tell you that it works.
Possibly, the drive has a hardware problem, that occurs when it is under a heavy load (like when encrypting). So look at the Smart values of the drive. Or take it out and have it checked with manufacturer tools.
Or fill it up with random data, or bitlock it as single drive for a test.

If all that looks good and only as raid member it fails, update your controller firmware and driver if possible.

Comment: Thank you, will check the SMART values, I remember it not being in perfect health. I was due for replacing the drive by EOY anyways, so I might just get a new drive and try it on a fresh one.

Comment: After running a chkdsk /f on the drive, it was kicked out of the array multiple times before outright failing - indeed must have been an issue with the drive. Marking this as the accepted answer, thank you very much for the input!